# Change in JSON generated for a System.Data.DataTable in a .NET Core project vs .NET Framework

Tags: c#, json, json.net, .net-core

The program below generates different JSON when run in a .NET Core project vs a .NET Framework app.

**Code**

```
class Program
{
    internal static readonly MediaTypeFormatter DefaultFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false,
        SerializerSettings =
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat
        }
    };

    private static DataTable BuildTestDataTable()
    {
        var testDataTable = new DataTable();
        testDataTable.Columns.Add("Label", typeof(string));
        testDataTable.Columns.Add("Metric", typeof(decimal));
        testDataTable.Rows.Add("A", 10);
        testDataTable.Rows.Add("B", 20);
        return testDataTable;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable table = BuildTestDataTable();

        ObjectContent oc = new ObjectContent(table.GetType(), table, DefaultFormatter);

        Console.WriteLine(oc.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

.Net Framework:

`[{"Label":"A","Metric":10.0},{"Label":"B","Metric":20.0}]`

.Net Core:

```
{
    "DataTable.RemotingVersion": {
        "_Major": 2,
        "_Minor": 0,
        "_Build": -1,
        "_Revision": -1
    },
    "XmlSchema": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<xs:schema xmlns=\"\" xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:msdata=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\">\r\n  <xs:element name=\"Table1\">\r\n    <xs:complexType>\r\n      <xs:sequence>\r\n        <xs:element name=\"Label\" type=\"xs:string\" msdata:targetNamespace=\"\" minOccurs=\"0\" />\r\n        <xs:element name=\"Metric\" type=\"xs:decimal\" msdata:targetNamespace=\"\" minOccurs=\"0\" />\r\n      </xs:sequence>\r\n    </xs:complexType>\r\n  </xs:element>\r\n  <xs:element name=\"tmpDataSet\" msdata:IsDataSet=\"true\" msdata:MainDataTable=\"Table1\" msdata:UseCurrentLocale=\"true\">\r\n    <xs:complexType>\r\n      <xs:choice minOccurs=\"0\" maxOccurs=\"unbounded\" />\r\n    </xs:complexType>\r\n  </xs:element>\r\n</xs:schema>",
    "XmlDiffGram": "<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\" xmlns:diffgr=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1\">\r\n  <tmpDataSet>\r\n    <Table1 diffgr:id=\"Table11\" msdata:rowOrder=\"0\" diffgr:hasChanges=\"inserted\">\r\n      <Label>A</Label>\r\n      <Metric>10</Metric>\r\n    </Table1>\r\n    <Table1 diffgr:id=\"Table12\" msdata:rowOrder=\"1\" diffgr:hasChanges=\"inserted\">\r\n      <Label>B</Label>\r\n      <Metric>20</Metric>\r\n    </Table1>\r\n  </tmpDataSet>\r\n</diffgr:diffgram>"
}
```

Can someone illuminate me on the cause of this, and whether it is an intentional difference ?

Comment: Why are you using a DataTable anyways? Why not pass around strongly typed objects?

Comment: That "DataTable.RemotingVersion" preamble looks like it's coming from DataTable's implementation of ISerializable
https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs#L235

Not sure why that's being invoked on .NET Core though (rather than using the JSON serializer)

Comment: I would guess the .net fx JsonMediaTypeFormatter has a special JsonConverter for DataTable and .net core don't, thats why .net core uses the info from ISerialization implementation

Comment: JsonMediaTypeFormatter uses internally Json.Net for serialization and Json.Net has a [DataTableConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_DataTableConverter.htm) which seems is only valid for .net Framework DataTable

Comment: Yes - the type DataTableConverter isn't even available in the .net core version of Newtonsoft.Json . . .

Comment: Have submitted an issue - https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1383

Comment: Here's a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45875950/433342

Comment: @mason SMH. In my case it's because the SQL result set has dynamic columns that are only known at runtime. Anyway there are loads of scenarios where copying a `DataRow` to a DTO instance doesn't make sense.

Comment: @RonnieOverby There are a few cases where it doesn't make sense, but I was specifically asking stevec to see what his use case was. Using a DataTable should be avoided when possible.

Comment: @mason Why should they be avoided when possible?

Comment: @RonnieOverby Because they're a poor abstraction for working with data. Linq is more cumbersome, they take up more memory to represent the same data, and can only represent flat data structures, they can't represent normalized hierarchical data. There are very few use cases for DataTable, such as SqlBulkCopy. In the majority of circumstances however, defining types to represent your data is far more preferable.

Comment: @mason Dataset and Datatable are poor abstractions for working with data? I swear I'm not attempting to troll you. I agree that in the general use-case, those types are cumbersome to work with. But I wouldn't call them poor abstractions. Nothing else that I know of represents a tabular result set with more fidelity. Sometimes, that's needed and sometimes it's not.

Comment: @RonnieOverby Yes, they're poor abstractions. No, they don't give more fidelity: they're slow, they're memory inefficient, more difficult to use Linq with, more difficult to refactor, can't represent normalized data unless it's a flat structure. It does have limited use cases, but you should ascertain whether you're actually in one of those use cases before using it, and that shouldn't be very often. The vast majority of the time it's better to create types to represent the data. I was trying to figure out whether this usage fell into one of those categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1383

> It is in netstandard1.5 but netstandard1.3 is the highest that Json.NET supports. When a netstandard2.0 build is eventually added then I'll add support for it.

Comment: Maybe just a little longer https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1383

Comment: They've fixed it now.