# JsonConvert DataSet .NET Core 2.0 not working

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net

[This example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDataSet.htm) no longer seems to work in .NET Core 2.0, it now serializes using an XmlDiffGram.  Any easy way to get it working?  Do I need to do this [whole thing](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Sep/03/DataTable-JSON-Serialization-in-JSONNET-and-JavaScriptSerializer)?

Comment: .NET Core is still infancy. I guess that you need wait for new version in order that your code will work. If your application is for windows then you can still use the .NET framework instead. If your application is not targeted only to windows and you're inpatient until .NET Core gets improved then I afraid that you need to do this "whole thing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looks like the Netonsoft crew have written a specific converters for [DataSet](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_DataSetConverter.htm) & [DataTables](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_DataTableConverter.htm) which should point you in the right direction.

Quick update:
It looks like these are not quite in the latest nuget release yet, but coming [soon](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1383).

when they are released, you'll need to change the line in the example to something like.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new[] { new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DataSetConverter() } });
```

Comment: Accepted as answer for pointing me to the newtonsoft ticket, fix the link though, its broken

Answer (score 2):

As of 25/04/2018. Download latest version of Newtonsoft. I upgraded to 11.0.2. It now works  with ASP Core 2. Datasets get converted to JSON.

Comment: Thanks Man. You made my day! Datatable automatically converts to JSON with this 11.0.2 newtonsoft package.

Answer (score 1):

Well this works...

```
var xml = new XDocument();
using (var writer = xml.CreateWriter())
{
    dataSet.WriteXml(writer);
    writer.Flush();
}
return Json(xml);
```