# C# Serializing DataTable result returned from sqlite is returing XML format

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using .net core(2.1) web application. I'm implementing the web API  where it will connect to SQLite DB and get the data and return the query result. Here is the code that I have used.

```
 using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=D:/SQL-Lite/xxxxx/test.db;Version=3;")) {
                connection.Open();

                using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    var selectCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                    selectCommand.Transaction = transaction;
                    selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employee";
                    var ds = new DataSet();
                    var da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(selectCommand);
                    da.Fill(ds);

                    if (ds.Tables != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                        response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
                }
            }
```

previously I have worked with SQL server and ASP.NET where I will get the JSON during serialization in the format of rows and columns. As below

[image]

Now I'm also getting some metadata in XML along with the actual data. I'm attaching the serialized data below.

```
{"DataTable.RemotingVersion":{"Major":2,"Minor":0,"Build":-1,"Revision":-1,"MajorRevision":-1,"MinorRevision":-1},"XmlSchema":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<xs:schema xmlns=\"\" xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:msdata=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\">\r\n  <xs:element name=\"Table\">\r\n    <xs:complexType>\r\n      <xs:sequence>\r\n        <xs:element name=\"Id\" type=\"xs:long\" msdata:targetNamespace=\"\" minOccurs=\"0\" />\r\n        <xs:element name=\"FirstName\" type=\"xs:string\" msdata:targetNamespace=\"\" minOccurs=\"0\" />\r\n        <xs:element name=\"Salary\" type=\"xs:double\" msdata:targetNamespace=\"\" minOccurs=\"0\" />\r\n        <xs:element name=\"Department\" type=\"xs:string\" msdata:targetNamespace=\"\" minOccurs=\"0\" />\r\n      </xs:sequence>\r\n    </xs:complexType>\r\n  </xs:element>\r\n  <xs:element name=\"tmpDataSet\" msdata:IsDataSet=\"true\" msdata:MainDataTable=\"Table\" msdata:UseCurrentLocale=\"true\">\r\n    <xs:complexType>\r\n      <xs:choice minOccurs=\"0\" maxOccurs=\"unbounded\" />\r\n    </xs:complexType>\r\n  </xs:element>\r\n</xs:schema>","XmlDiffGram":"<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\" xmlns:diffgr=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1\">\r\n  <tmpDataSet>\r\n    <Table diffgr:id=\"Table1\" msdata:rowOrder=\"0\">\r\n      <Id>11</Id>\r\n      <FirstName>nithin</FirstName>\r\n      <Salary>5000</Salary>\r\n      <Department>CSE</Department>\r\n    </Table>\r\n  </tmpDataSet>\r\n</diffgr:diffgram>"}
```

How can I avoid these other data and only get the actual query result (rows & columns) during serialization?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

Parsing classes:

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("DataTable.RemotingVersion")]
    public object RemotingVersion { get; set; }

    public string XmlSchema { get; set; }

    public string XmlDiffGram { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

And usage:

```
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(response);
var doc = XDocument.Parse(res.XmlDiffGram);
var table = doc.Root.XPathSelectElement("tmpDataSet/Table");
var data = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Table)).Deserialize(table.CreateReader());
```

Comment: thanks for your work. But I have found the reason why this occurs as because the below issue. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194984/change-in-json-generated-for-a-system-data-datatable-in-a-net-core-project-vs
https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1383